# How to execute decorated class methods stored in a list object?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to store class methods into a list and execute them via a loop. I defined a decorator and use it to append class methods to a list. The class is defined in a separate module and in the main I loop thru the list and call the class methods stored in that list. When I run main, I got the error:

TypeError: example_01() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I'm kinda know that I will need to create an instance of class Bar to execute its method but this would prevent me to use the list. what would be a correct way to use such construct ?
Please help ...

I'm using python 3.4

Thanks

```
mybar.py
========

examples = list()

def example(fn):
    try: name = 'Example %d' % int(fn.__name__[7:])
    except: name = fn.__name__

    def wrapped():
        print('Running: %s\n' % name)
        fn()
        print('\n')
    examples.append(wrapped)
    return wrapped


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "I'm %s" % (__name__)

    @example
    def example_01(self):
       print(self.message)
       print("Executing example_01")

    @example
    def example_02(selfs):
        print(self.message)
        print("Executing example_02")

main.py
=======
from bar import mybar


def main():
    for example in mybar.examples:
        example()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I modified my code to use @classmethod decorator for each class method and it works, but I don't understand why. I don't have to explicitly call example() with Bar. nor providing the class object to the class function's argument like def example_01(cls) as documented in python doc. Could someone please explain

```
mybar.py
=======
class Bar:
data = 25
def __init__(self):
    self.message = "I'm %s" % (__name__)
    Bar.data = 30

@classmethod
@example
def example_01():
    print("Executing example_01")
    print("Data: ", Bar.data)

@classmethod
@example
def example_02():
    print("Executing example_02")
    print("Data: ", Bar.data)
```

## output:

```
Running: example_01
Executing example_01
Data:  25
Running: example_02
Executing example_02
Data:  25
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is a distinction between a function (which takes a plain list of arguments) and a method (which takes arguments plus a special `self` or `cls` argument).  A function becomes a method once it is assigned to a variable inside a class namespace.

At the point in time when you are decorating the functions `example_01` and `example_02`, they aren't actually methods but plain functions.  It's these functions which you are appending to `examples`, so your resulting class methods aren't ever called.

You can't solve this in an easy way.  Either you decorate with `@example` first (then you don't have class methods yet), or you decorate with `@classmethod` first (then all you have is an intermediate object which isn't a class method either).  The only way to get the final class method is to *retrieve* the method from the class *after* it has been assigned, which obviously can't be done from the decorator.

The easiest thing would be to drop the decorator altogether and assign the class methods to `examples` in a straightforward way:

```
examples = [Bar.example_01, Bar.example_02]
```

If you really want to use a decorator, you could put a wrapper in `examples` which retrieves the class method from the class by its name using `getattr` and returns the *unmodified* function `fn`.

Note that since the `message` variable is set in the constructor of the class `Bar`, you need a `Bar` instance to access it.  If you want to access a variable from a class method without creating a dummy instance, you have to set it in the class namespace instead.  However, the `__name__` variable isn't set there, so you basically can't use a `message` variable like you were intending to.  Also, in a class method, the first argument is the class itself (usually called `cls`), not `self` (an instance), and a `print` statement which ends with `\n` results in a double line break.

This is what the final code could look like:

```
examples = list()

def example(fn):
    def wrapped():
        print("Running: %s" % fn.__name__)
        getattr(Bar, fn.__name__)()
        print()
    examples.append(wrapped)
    return fn

class Bar:
    @classmethod
    @example
    def example_01(cls):
       print("I'm %s" % cls.__name__)
       print("Executing example_01")

    @classmethod
    @example
    def example_02(cls):
        print("I'm %s" % cls.__name__)
        print("Executing example_02")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use decorators, you can retrieve the list of methods of a class and use the method __getattribute__() to call each method from an instance of the class. Here is the code:

```
import types

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "I'm %s" % (self.__class__.__name__)

    def example_01(self):
       print(self.message)
       print("Executing example_01")

    def example_02(self):
        print(self.message)
        print("Executing example_02")

examples = list()
testBar = Bar()
methods = Bar.__dict__
for k, v in methods.items():
    if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
        if k != '__init__':
            examples.append(testBar.__getattribute__(k))

def main():
    for method in examples:
        method()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```